# getReviewsSummaryHtml shortcode isn't converted (magento)

Tags: php

For some days a function in a `.phtml` file creates a incorrect output. It seems that a shortcode isn't correct converted. I looked at the code and this line is causing it:

```
<?php $_products = $this->getProductCollection(); ?>
...
<?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short', false) ?>
```

It creates this output:

```
{{{(0)}}{{(%d)}}{{(%d)}}{{Mage_Review}}}
```

Some days ago I hadn't this problem. I don't know what I changed so that this occured. How can I fix this?